# iOS - Getting information from the View Controller to drawRect in the View

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cs193p

My question relates to Assignment 3 in CS193p.

Im having a terrible time getting `drawRect` in my View to receive information passed from my View Controller.  Basically, my goal is to pass view-specific information (like `self.view.size.width`) to the controller, have it make some modifications (like `result = self.view.size.width * 2`), and pass `result` back to `drawRect` so that it could take the new info and draw it.  Im pretty sure I have my delegation set up correctly, and really have tried a list of potential work-arounds:

- make a public View `@property`, which I access in my `controller.m` via

  View *newView
  someResult = newView.variable

which I would then try to access from my `view.m` via

```
self.variable
```

- use methods set in my View's `@protocal`, which I try to pass data via `myView.dataSource someMethod:someData`

But so far none of these are currently working (i.e. my `self.variable` would always come out to be 0, which shows that no data was passed to it).  Your help much appreciated!

UPDATE:

The culprit was that, in the storyboard, **I didn't control-drag the View Controller to the View**, and hence the Controller was never connected... but at least now it works. ^_^

Comment: Is this the correct description of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

`View *newView someResult = newView.variable` is not valid syntax.
If `newView.variable` is not of type `View` then that is a problem.

If `newView` is already declared, you would access `variable` using `int myValue = newView.variable` (that is, asuming it is of int type).

An example would be:

```
// Somewhere in your code, you declare your object
UIView *otherView = [[UIView alloc] init];

// Somewhere else, you set a variable of your object
otherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// Again, somewhere else you want to access that value
UIColor *thatColor = otherView.backgroundColor;
```

I hope this explains it well enough.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I finally figured it out, and the culprit was that I didn't draw the View Controller to the View in the storyboard.. -_-.  At least my 2 days of frustration is over.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the correct description of what you want to do? You have a view controller (presumably the calculator type view controller from the course) and you want to communicate between that view controller (whose view has the calculator buttons) and a view other than it's own?

If so, here are the steps you should take:

In your view that you want to receive information from a delegate:

Declare an `@protocol` with the method you want the delegate to implement. Declare a property in the header file of the view that conforms to the aforementioned delegate: `@property (nonatomic, weak) delegate<NameOfTheProtocol> delegate;`

In the view controller you want to act as the delegate, declare it conforms to the protocol: `MyClass: UIViewController <NameOfTheProtocol>`. In the implementation file of that view controller, implement the methods of the protocol. Where ever you create the view that you want to receive information, set it's `delegate` property to your view controller.

To pass information between them (I have no idea what information you want to pass), your protocol method might be something like: `-(CGPoint)pointToDrawAtGivenPosition:(CGPoint)point`

In your view that has the delegate property, you could in drawRect do something like:

`CGPoint pointToDrawAt = [self.delegate pointToDrawAtGivenPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100)];`
`//Now draw that point or whatever.`

Basically, the view is asking its delegate to make a decision about where to draw something. It passes some information to the delegate, and the delegate responds with the correct position for the view to draw at.

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed walkthrough - the delegation part was particularly helpful.  I found out that I didn't control-drag the view controller to the view in the storyboard, and so the two were not talking to each other.. and so now everything works.  Thanks for the help regardless! ^_^